# avoid repeating jquery event bindings

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery

I got into a situation where some of the page contents are partially getting loaded in ajax, and that adds one compiled js including jquery_ujs, which then repeats all ujs events, like for instance when you click on delete you get confirmation, its getting repeated.

Hence wanted to know how to avoid repeating of event binding by any trick and not ensuring js is not re-reloaded in general. Or is there any flag or control in ujs, I did not find though, we could achieve this, so re-load ujs any time but get event binding only once.

hmm...Why not event binding is idempotent?

Is there any solution apart from keeping apart such js files and ensuring they get loaded only once?

And btw, is there any tool which detects such repeated bindings?

Comment: You mentioned your best solution, don't load the js files back into the document. Why are you returning that in your AJAX call, I assume the endpoint is something you created?

Comment: right, I created the endpoint. Some of my pages do require that js, few not. I could control that separating imported js entries.

Comment: They require it to be returned in the AJAX call?

Comment: yes, now I am creating a xhr version of js file which would only hold the things that are require

Comment: You should almost always use [delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) when dealing with content via ajax, that way you don't have to re-bind or re-fire javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you should use a cleaner method, sometimes when you're working on someone else's code and just need a quick fix to ensure an event isn't set up more than once (with nebulous code) then I've done this:

```
$(someSelector).off('click').on('click', function(event)
{
    // whatever
});
```

Comment: point 1: yes this is good approach, I hope most of us follow the same

Comment: point 3: how do we look after 3rd party js files not owned by us

Comment: Re point 2, I think it would be wrong for jQuery to assume that you want to replace an existing event as you may programmatically be wanted to add another one that does something else. (This being said, almost all the time you typically want to replace existing events.)

Comment: Re point 2, jquery does provide some friendly apis, `on`, `live`, `delegate` and may be more, this would be another flavor. But yes you are right too on other side

Answer (score 1):

If you find garbage in house, will you clean it or decorate it?

It's your duty to make sure no unnecessary js loaded. Just as simple as that.

Comment: Am looking for a beautiful maid who will do that for me

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$(selector).on('click',function(){
  //do stuff here
  $(this).off('click');
});
```

Or you can use something like this:

```
var clicked = false;
$(selector).on('click',function(){
  if(!clicked){
  clicked = true;
  //do stuff here

  .....somefunc(){
  clicked = false;
  }
  ...
  }
});
```

Comment: If there was already a click event set up on selector, wouldn't that add another one, so both could get fired, then the off event would permanently get rid of both of the events instead of leaving one bound?

Comment: As the OP says : when you click on delete you get confirmation, its getting repeated.

Comment: Yes, that was the point I was trying to express. I think that the original plus your new event could both fire if say the original fires first. (What the OP was trying to avoid.) Then on the last line of your new event, both events are disabled rather than leaving just one enabled I think. Sorry if I wasn't clear in my original comment.

Answer (score 0):

There is something known as Self**-Defining Functions** in Javascript. This pattern is useful when your function has some initial prepatory work to do and it needs to do it only once. In such case, the self-defining function can update its own implementation.

For e.g

```
var shout= function(){
    alert('shout!');
    shout= function(){
          alert('shout again');
   }
}

//using self-defining function
shout(); // shout!
shout(); // shout again!
```

Hope this would be useful to you.